# Remainder Taylor series two+ variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion, error-function

Hard to find an article /  tutorial specifically about this subject online....
Can anyone explain / send link to explanation or tutorial regarding how to calculate remainder for multi-variable taylor series?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 3):

You can check this file "Higher-Order Derivatives and Taylor’s Formula in Several Variables"
By: G. B. Folland
https://sites.math.washington.edu/~folland/Math425/taylor2.pdf

Comment: Many thanks bro.